# macro to check non blank cells in a column to ensure isdate()

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking to write a macro to check 3 columns to ensure the contents are a date value. The columns **can** contain empty cells.

The below returns a message box for each cell that is not a date, even the blanks.

```
Sub DateCheck()
With ActiveSheet
   lastRow = .Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For RowCount = 2 To lastRow
      POC = .Range("AB" & RowCount)
   If Not IsDate(POC) Then
       MsgBox ("Please enter valid date in Cell : AB" & RowCount & ". Example: dd/mm/yyyy")
   End If
  Next RowCount

   End With
End Sub
```

Could anybody be so kind as to help to adjust this to look at 3 non-adjacent columns, ignore blank cells and only return one message per column in the event it finds non-date values?

Thanks as always

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your loop to a `For Each In ... Next` and use `.Union` to construct a range of non-adjacent columns.

```
Sub MultiDateCheck()
    Dim lr As Long, cl As Range, rng As Range, mssg As String
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Union(.Range("AB2:AB" & lr), .Range("AM2:AM" & lr), .Range("AZ2:AZ" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
            If Not IsDate(cl.Value) And Not IsEmpty(cl) Then _
                mssg = mssg & cl.Address(0, 0) & Space(4)
        Next cl
    End With
    If CBool(Len(mssg)) Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter valid date(s) in Cell(s): " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
          mssg & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
          "Example: dd/mm/yyyy")
    Else
        MsgBox "All dates completed!"
    End If
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've used a single *lastrow* from column AB to determined the scope of the cells to be examined but individual rows for each column could easily be compensated for.

*Addendum:* Code modified for a single message showing rogue non-date/non-blank cells (as below). The `Chr(10)` is simply a *line feed* character.

[image: Sample error message]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. The advice on .union has been really useful in a couple of other issues I have. Once again thank you.

Comment: One further quick question, is there a way to show only one error message. As an example I tested this on a sheet there were 1000+ non-valid dates, to clear the error message involved pressing the ok button a lot. Thank you once again.

Comment: @chris1982 - I'm glad you got sorted out. I've adjusted the code above as per the last part of your original request. Thanks for the positive feedback!

Answer (score 2):

## Code:

```
Sub DateCheck()
    Dim s(2) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim o As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    'Enter columns here:
    s(0) = "A"
    s(1) = "B"
    s(2) = "C"
    
    
For i = 0 To 2
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range(s(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastRow
            POC = .Range(s(i) & r)
            
            If Not IsDate(POC) Then
                o = o & ", " & .Range(s(i) & r).Address
            End If
        Next r
        MsgBox ("Please enter valid date in Cells : " & Right(o, Len(o) - 1) & ". Example: dd/mm/yyyy")
        o = ""
   End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested this approach but I got an error on the "MsgBox". When I have a couple of minutes I will look at this again as I do like the way this is written. Makes me realise how poor my vba skills are! Thank you for taking the time to post an answer!